# Question about a harmonic oscillator

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

I was solving the following problem on harmonic oscillation and I don't understand a specific part in the proof. I will *emphasize (italic)* the part which I don't understand.

**Problem:**
The following system is considered: Consider a rigid, massless bar that connects a body of mass $m$ (lower) and another body of mass $m'$ (upper). There exists a fixed articulation point $A$ such that the distance between $A$ and $m$ is $R$ and the distance between $A$ and $m'$ is $r$. The body $m$ is moved slightly to the left. Find the period of oscillation $T$.

[image: System at rest]
[image: System in motion]

**My approach:**
Consider the potential energy of the system at rest. Its potential energy, by setting zero potential energy at the point where $m$ lies, we find potential energy $E_{p, \ eq} = m'g(R+r).$ Now, the potential energy of the system for an angular deviation $\alpha$ is equal to $E_{p, \ system}= mgR(1-\cos \alpha) + m'g(R+r \cos \alpha)$. Now, since we want the potential energy of the oscillator to be zero when the body is in its equilibrium position (left image), we must substract the potential energy in equilibrium from the general potential energy, to obtain the potential energy of the oscillator $$E_p(\alpha) = (mR - m'r)g(1-\cos \alpha) \approx \frac{1}{2} (mR - m'r)g \alpha^2$$
For small oscillations, we took $1- \cos \alpha = 2 \sin^2 (\alpha/2) \approx \alpha^2/2$. Additionally, *the displacement is written as approximately $x=\alpha R$, obtaining the potential energy of the form* $E_p = \frac{1}{2} k_e x^2$, where $k_e$ is the equivalent elasticity coefficient:
$$E_p(x) = \frac{1}{2} \frac{mg}{R} \left( 1 - \frac{m'}{m} \frac{r}{R} \right) x^2 \quad \Rightarrow \quad  k_e = \frac{mg}{R} \left( 1 - \frac{m'}{m} \frac{r}{R} \right)$$
*However, I do not know how the equivalent mass is determined.* If determined, the period is $T=2 \pi \sqrt{m_e/k_e}$.

**The author's approach:** *The author, without explaining notation, writes these equations:
The kinetic energy is*
$$E_c = \frac{1}{2} mv^2 + \frac{1}{2} m'v'^2 = \frac{1}{2}  m \left[ 1 + \frac{m'}{m} \left( \frac{r}{R} \right)^2 \right] v_x^2 \quad \Rightarrow \quad m_e = m \left[ 1 + \frac{m'}{m} \left( \frac{r}{R} \right)^2 \right]$$

**Question:**

1. Why isn't the equivalent mass just the sum of the two bodies, i.e. $m_e = m+m'$? Is there a formula or general method of determining the equivalent mass?
2. If we take an equivalent mass, why do we take a different velocity $v_x \neq v$, i.e. why do we still calculate the displacement of the body starting from the equilibrium position of $m$? Why not $m'$? Why not from the center of mass of the system?
3. In my approach, I also italicized the equation $x = \alpha R$. If we are working with a multiple body system, why do we take the radius (distance between articulation point and oscillator reference frame) to be $R$ (from $A$ to $m$) and not $r'$ (from $A$ to $m'$) or any other distance?
4. On a more general note, say I consider the classical gravitational pendulum and I want to calculate the period of oscillation of the point which is in the middle between the articulation point and oscillating body $m$. If I were to set a reference frame there, everything would be the same but why don't I set $x = \alpha R/2$? (If I set $x =\alpha R/2$ I get that the period of oscillation would be $2\pi \sqrt{2m/R}$ which is different than the period of oscillation of the body, absolute nonsense!). As such, how do I know to put that $R$ and not something else?

I suspect that Q4 is a general consequence of Q1, Q2, Q3 but I am still posing it here if that's not the case.

Comment: The point is to reduce the motion to a single coordinate.  You just need to be sure that your velocity is also the time rate of change of that coordinate.  Things will work out correctly no matter which convention you choose as long as you are consistent.  You could equally use the position of the upper mass, you would get different values for $x$ and $v$, but the resulting motion described would be the same with the same period.

Comment: So in the case where our coordinate $x$ is the displacement of the bottom mass once you have determined that the total kinetic energy of the system in that coordinate is of the form ${1 \over 2} M v^2$, (where $v$ is the time derivative of that $x$) then $M$ IS the effective mass.